# How to label a dynamic KML file in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, labeling

How can I display labels for features in a KML file on an OpenLayers map. I was thinking of using popup messages, but labels are more attractive and eye-catching.

I want to replicate the labeling method of Google Earth:

[image]

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: zearth, didn't you mean labling features imported from a KML *file*? The example has lables but it's labling features that are defined in the same file...

Comment: John Doe, oh yeah. It's like we are using imported KML file. The labeling method shown below are features, not KML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked the [OpenLayers Labeled features example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features-with-text.html)?

[image]

```
        var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Simple Geometry", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default':{
                strokeColor: "#00FF00",
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWidth: 3,
                fillColor: "#FF5500",
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                pointRadius: 6,
                pointerEvents: "visiblePainted",
                // label with \n linebreaks
                label : "name: ${name}\n\nage: ${age}",

                fontColor: "${favColor}",
                fontSize: "12px",
                fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                labelAlign: "${align}",
                labelXOffset: "${xOffset}",
                labelYOffset: "${yOffset}"
            }}),
            renderers: renderer
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @underdark. Besides, I already using this example too. But, I'm thinking more like KML label that refresh simultaneously. Is that even possible? Like we view in Google Earth.

Comment: Currently using this coding till I find better answer.

Answer (score 0):

My homework on this suggests placemark labels in google maps are hardly supported. But I find that hard to believe. 
I'd like to be using placemark labels on google maps kml which originates from Spreadsheet Mapper 2.0. Anyone done that?